# I have a problem connecting to my db on godaddy with PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo, shared-hosting

I have been trying to connect to my database using pdo on godaddy with no successs.

Initially i got the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Then i look around the web, found out that i need to change the part to socket. I looked for my socket found it and changed it using `unix_socket=/tmp/mysql-1.sock`. Now i get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql-1.sock' (2)
```

I have also tried changing the host and hostname to the IP address of server hosting the database and still get the same error.

Please can someone help me. Im hosting on godaddy.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT #1

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql: hostname=122.100.111.0;port=3306;unix_socket=/tmp/mysql-1.sock; dbname=orson', 'username', 'password');
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from q_users') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";

}
```

Comment: Paste your code. You are trying to connect to localhost when your database is in another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exchanging messages with the Godaddy Support Team i found out that they don't support PDO on their shared hosting plan.

Comment: I'd say this anyway, but drop them like a rock.  There is no reason at all whatsoever that they should not support PDO.  (That being said, your error is due to MySQL looking for a socket file instead of trying to connect to a port...)

Comment: mysqlnd driver, getResult() and all not supported, Creating Trigger not supported, Creating Function not supported. Then what else do they support?? Ah... **All types of Credit Cards are supported**

Answer (score 4):

PDO is supported on the Linux hosting plans at **GoDaddy** but apparently has to be enabled through cPanel on some accounts:

1. Go to cPanel from Hosting menu under My Account.
2. Go to "**Select PHP version**".
3. Choose version of PHP in dropbox (e.g. 5.5) and click "**Set as Current**".
4. Check the checkboxes of the features you want (e.g. PDO) and click "**Save**".

> **Note:**  You may need to check other boxes that one would normally think
>   are on by default (e.g. mysqli).

*Spent some time tonight talking to GoDaddy tech support to figure this out and thought I would share.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I think your hostname its wrong. Here´s a document where you can find your hostname. They do support PDO I have my entire application running with it.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/39/locating-your-databases-host-name

Comment: They didn't support it in 2010. Maybe now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue!

After looking through their forums, I've found Go Daddy's Windows platform does not support it, their Linux one however does. They do not charge you to switch.